# How to fix AdsError 1792 (0X700) for TwinCAT 3

Tags: twincat, twincat-ads, twincat-ads-.net

I am using a Windows PC as my Development PC (XAE) and another Windows PC as my Remote PC (XAR). I have connected them successfully. It is shown in the picture below.
[image: successfully Connected]

But, this error appeared when I tried to Activate the configuration after connecting to the Runtime PC. This error AdsError: 1792 (0X700) appeared on both (Development PC and the Runtime PC simultaneously).

I have already done the TCP and UDP settings.

[image: Error Picture]

Kindly view the event viewer error picture.
[image: Event Viewer Picyure]

Comment: Tip: you can put a `!` in front of the `[]` of image links to show the actual images in the post. See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Did you google the error code?

Comment: I have tried it but the website is not allowing me. They are suggesting that you must have at least 10 reputations to post a picture.

Comment: Ah that is why none of the new users post pictures. I was wondering why that happened so often.

Comment: Now you can edit it

Answer (score 1):

For future me and others, the comment from Hugh Wang about running the .reg file is what resolved this issue for me. We were setting up a fresh Cx5240 and having issues loading config to the processor.

Comment: please actually state what the answer is instead of saying there's a comment here that is the answer. see also [/help/referencing](/help/referencing)

Answer (score -1):

Please reference the following link
https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_security_management/1850044555.html&id=

If you are using versioned C++ project, you should check the "**Sign TwinCAT C++ executables (*.tmx)**" checkbox. Otherwise you get an error such as

```
ERR | 12/14/2021 10:24:58 AM 051 ms | 'TCOM Server' (10): Error loading repository driver 'C:\TwinCAT\3.1\Boot\Repository\C++ Module Vendor\StateMachineDrv\0.0.0.1\StateMachineDrv' - hr = 0xc0000603
```

[image: checkbox]

Comment: This step is already done.

Comment: Did you run *.reg in the directory C:\TwinCAT\3.1\Target\OemCertificates?       

ERR | 12/23/2021 10:28:57 AM 335 ms | 'TCOM Server' (10): OEM ****** certificate currently not trusted. Import 'C:\TwinCAT\3.1\Target\OemCertificates\******_c9a22481-f61c-d8c9-bd06-8f8123e7ab4c.reg' to add OEM to trusted list
...